# Visual Studio 2015, no syntax highlighting for XML files

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2015, wix, app-config

In Visual Studio 2015 sp3, after installing Wix Toolset 3.11 and Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2015 Extension 0.9.21.62588 there is not syntax highlighting. I have tried reinstalling both, with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Edit: It's not only wxs files, but any xml file like app.config, xml, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the solution, just in case it could help someone else.

Open Visual Studio command prompt and run:

```
devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

After opening the project, syntax highlighting is back. And is still there after closing and reopening as usual from menu shortcut.